# CSS Blur Background with Transparency (like in iOS7)

Tags: css, background, filter, transparent, blur

This is for a website header that sticks to the top and have rest of the body scroll underneath it.

So far, I managed to get the transparency working; however, I do want to blur the background of the header so when rest of the content scrolls underneath it, content looks blurred.  Is this possible?

The look I am trying to achieve is just like on iOS 7.  Their new tool bars have the same effect.

```
#headerWrapperBackground {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 9998;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #222;
    background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.95);

}

#headerWrapper {
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 5px 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<svg height="110" width="110">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect width="90" height="90" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" fill="gray" filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: No luck with that. Not getting blur.  Well In order to gain transparency, I had to make that opacity 0.9.  I am not sure if THAT took away the blur effect.